# Is there any offline javascript API document tool available like YARD for ruby does?

Tags: javascript, code-documentation

Mozilla online documentation are great, but sometimes I don't have the internet connection and  reference in the o'reilly javascript definitive guide is also great but lack of the handy searchable capability.

I just wonder if there anything for javascript like [railsapi](http://railsapi.com/), or [yard](http://yardoc.org/), or [jQAPI](http://jqapi.com/)

Comment: Good question. Going back ten years I used to rely on a local install of MSDN, but I'd love to know about a current (and free) offline reference.

Comment: @nnnnnn same thing happen to me in 2012, when I want to check some methods of a certain object, I'm looking into O'reilly Javascript guide, it's a great book, but It's not elegant, somebody give me a better way?

Answer (score 1):

http://devdocs.io Searchable offline documentation for JavaScript, DOM Events, HTML, CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can probably blame the lack of uniform documentation styles and the fact that there is no centrally approved Javascript "stdlib", but there seems to be no such off-line doc generators or generated documentation.

There is, strangely, a certain amount of documentation available as Windows help files (CHM):

- http://prototypejs.org/api,
- http://docs.jquery.com/Alternative_Resources,
- there are mootools CHM floating around the web as well.

Comment: Thanks for the resources you've provided here, but what am I looking for is a offline reference with search and list function like YARD in Ruby

Comment: prototypejs 's dashboard widget is cool. but it link back to the web. no local storage. .

Comment: in that prototypejs page there is a link to the CHM and PDF files that you can use offline with CHM and PDF readers (that usually have search features).

Answer (score 0):

[Heronotes](https://code.google.com/p/heronote/) provides you many offline version of good api's documentation, including, HTML, CSS, jQuery, Ruby, Prototype etc...

All the best:)